# Find all intervals [s,e] where s,e in N_0 and s < e that overlap with another given interval

Tags: algorithm, sorting, processing-efficiency

I have an algorithmic problem where I would like to see if it can be solved in better than O(n):

I have given a table T of n elements where each element is a tuple (s_i, e_i) with s_i, e_i in N and s_i < e_i, i.e. each tuple is some kind of an interval. I have to find all intervals that overlap with a given interval [t0, t1] with t0, t1 in N and t0 < t1. Further, I have available two sorted lists S and E, containing the s values, or e values respectively, together with the index i pointing to the respective entry in T. The lists are sorted by s values, or e values respectively. (Let's assume both, s and e values, are unique.)

Problem:

We have to find each interval/tuple (s_i, e_i) in T where s_i <= t1 and e_i >= t0.

My thoughts so far:

We can exclude some elements by either applying one of the interval boundaries, i.e. searching t1 in S or t0 in E. This gives us a list L of remaining elements:

```
L <- {e in E | e >= t0} or L <- {s in S | s <= t1}
```

However, there is no lower bound on the number of elements in L, no matter which search we perform. Further, we have to check every element in L if s <= t1, or e >= t0 respectively depending on which search we performed before.

The complexity for this solution is O(n).

However, let's say that k is the maximum number of elements overlapping with interval [t0, t1]. If we assume k << n, then the complexity is O(n/2) since we can exclude at least n/2 elements by choosing the appropriate search for L. Still O(n/2) is in O(n).

Can you think of a better approach to solve this problem?

(Please feel free to improve this question. Maybe it's not very clear. Thanks)

Comment: This may be better asked at http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more appropriate on cs.stackexchange.com or math.stackexchange.com.


Comment: Thanks, I already copied this question to http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14311/find-all-intervals-s-e-where-s-e-in-mathbbn-and-s-e-that-overlap . I don't know how to 'move' this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found at [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14311/find-all-intervals-s-e-where-s-e-in-mathbbn-and-s-e-that-overlap): The general problem cannot be solved in less than O(n). [Interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) provide O(log n) + O(k) complexity for searching intervals that overlap with a certain other interval, given that k is the number of overlapping intervals.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know anything about `k`, the number of intervals in the answer, you can't beat `O(N)`, as the result can have N intervals in it.

If you know k is a lot smaller than N, you may do something better. Using a binary search, you can find the last i0 that `s_i<t0` and the first i1 that `s_i1>t1`.

Then you find the last j0 that `e_j0<t0` and the first j1 that `e_j1>t1`.

The results are between max(i0,j0) and min(i1, j1). So you have O(logN) + O(k).

Comment: I have little doubts that this works, because max(i0,j0) or respectively min(i1,j1) do not give any range of values since table T is not ordered nor can we apply any order to T. However, this is necessary if we want to compare i0 and j0 (i1 and j1). Please clarify if I am wrong or if I missed some constraints. Thanks!

Comment: Don't S and E contain the sorted intervals?

Comment: They do, but S contains the s values and E the e values. However, index j cannot by searched for in S and i cannot be searched for in E. For instance, let's say T contains 0->(1,10), 1->(2,3), 2->(3,4), 3->(4,8), 4->(8,9), 5->(9,12), ... and we search for intervals overlapping with (5,7). With your solution, wouldn't we get i0 = 3, i1=4, j0=2 and j1=3 and solutions are in [max(i0,j0), min(i1,j1)] = [3,3]. Here we would miss interval i=0->(1,10).